# Iphone app on Ipad - make Ipad select 640x960 instead of pixelated 2x320x480

Tags: iphone, ipad, retina-display

This is for avoiding an extra target and writing any target-specific adaptation code for the Ipad, separate apps on App Store, etc etc - but instead let the Iphone app display in 640x960 rather than 320x480@2x using the "2x" button.

Even on a non-retina Ipad, there's room for 640x960, but the Ipad is still running Iphone apps on the Ipad as if they were made only for Iphone 3GS.

This is for an app used internally by a company and any authorized client/partner. The company has bought Ipads, but the clients/partners may want to use the Iphones they have.

So, I'm looking for a compile-time target flag or a snippet of code to execute to detect the platform is Ipad and make it display the window full-size.

Has someone succeeded in doing this and if so, how did you achieve it?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible without jail-breaking. If your iPhone app supports retina display, it will display with better results on the New iPad.

Comment: It does, and my memory is it still looks pixelated like on the non retina one. I'll double-check. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259921/how-to-make-an-iphone-and-iphone4-retina-compatible-app-done-in-cocoa-easily-a?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really how things work ... you're trying to create a workaround that will probably take you longer to get to work (if at all possible) than it would if you just commit to making iPad friendly layouts.

If you just make the project a universal binary, then it would run "natively" on the ipad rather than in iphone compatibility mode. After that, the simplest thing you could do is just make sure your view's resize masks are set correctly so they stretch. Depending on the complexity and makeup of your app, many times this is enough to get you through. However, in many cases it would behoove you to just make an ipad specific layout as usability is oftentimes greatly improved.

Comment: Usability is not affected here, because although the app is quite complex, almost all of the views are UIViews on a scrollview, or lists in the form of table views, for entering data. The workaround is necessary only because Apple chooses to not (yet?) update the eminent feature of running Iphone apps on Ipad to support 2010 devices and later (I don't know for a fact they haven't done so in OS 6 and realize I may have too high expectations -- it just seems a relatively simple thing to do, as simple as providing a 2x button, at least).